# How to break out of a foreach-loop when all filtered objects have been deleted?

Tags: php, foreach

I am using the following foreach-loop to display some products and their attributes in a html-table, which works without problems:

```
<?php
$obj=new Crud;
$obj->read();
?>

<div class="product_table">
<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Image</td>
    <td>action</td>
  </tr>

<?php

foreach($obj->data as $val){
    extract($val);

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $category_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $price; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $image; ?></td>
     <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Edit</a>  |  <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
    <?php
    }
?>
</table>
</div>

</div>
```

However, when I delete all products, the foreach loop will display the following error-message, because logically there are no products left:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Crud::$data in ...

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...
```

I already tried to check if `Crud::$data` or `$val` are empty like so:

```
if (empty(Crud::$data) {
   break;
   echo "No products listed.";
   }
```

But either no products are listed any longer (although present) or the error message remains.

How do I break out of the foreach-loop when no items are left?

Comment: Try to check with `isset()` instead of empty. If the undefined property is not set `!isset(Crud::$data)` break the loop.

Comment: Deleting all the elements of an array should result in an empty array, but the property should still be there. I think there's a problem with your deletion function.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by break out of the loop?  Do you mean not enter the loop when `$obj->data` is empty?  I don't see where you are deleting anything while in the loop, so no need to break out of it.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the problem is in your constructor. The initial value of `Crud::$data` should be an empty array, and `Crud::read()` should add to it. If the array is empty, the `for` loop will just end immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on if `$obj->data` is not an array or doesn't exist:

If not an array, don't run the loop:

```
if(is_array($obj->data)) {
    foreach($obj->data as $val){
```

If not set or not an array, don't run the loop:

```
if(isset($obj->data) && is_array($obj->data)) {
    foreach($obj->data as $val){
```